# Keeping data from a form to another

Tags: ms-access

This is my first question :)
I have a form in Access 2010 where the user inserts some fields (textbox, combobox...). When I navigate through records by clicking on the right and left arrows below the access mask some values (namely that ones selected through comboboxes) expire...
I need to keep the fields selected in the comboboxes saved in the form, how can I do it?
In addition, I would like that the value selected from the user in the combobox will remain after I close and reopen the form

I tried with this but it does not work:

```
Private Sub CasellaCombinata451_AfterUpdate()
    Me.CasellaCombinata451.DefaultValue = """" & Me!CasellaCombinata451 & """"
End Sub
```

Feel free to ask more info

Thanks in advance
Beppe

Comment: The default value will only work for new records - not existing ones. 
The only sensible way you can store the values as a default for that user the next time they open the form would be to store them in a local table.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to do this, but if you want to, you can.

The following code permanently alters the form to set the last value to the new default value.

```vb
Private Sub CasellaCombinata451_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.OpenForm Me.Name, acLayout
    Me.CasellaCombinata451.DefaultValue = "=""" & Me.CasellaCombinata451.Value & """"
    DoCmd.Save
    DoCmd.OpenForm Me.Name
End Sub
```

This code changes the view to layout view (because in normal view you can't permanently alter the form), then alters the form, then saves it, and then changes it to normal view again. This process usually saves the current record, but stays navigated on the same record, and requires exclusive access to the database.

As Minty suggested, if you want to save these values per user, and make them persist even after the database closes, the best way to go is just save them in a table. You can retrieve them with `DLookUp`, and set them as default.

If you don't need them to persist after closing and re-opening the database, a `TempVar` is the right place to store these values.

Implementation with a `TempVar`:

First, set the default value for your combo box equal to `TempVars!previousValue`.
Then, add the following code on your after update:

```vb
Private Sub CasellaCombinata451_AfterUpdate()
    TempVars!previousValue = Me!CasellaCombinata451
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if a user is using Access runtime - Layout and design mode aren't available to them. Or if it's a complied .accde file..

Comment: @Minty probably true, and as said, this is not a good plan, purely posting it here for educational purposes. Table or TempVar is the way to go, and those will work with both.